# Extract year from date column in dataframe having 'different date format" - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime-format

I have date's in different date formats in date column of dataframe.
like this:

```
print(df['date'].head(15))

5/27/1972
12/15/1979
10/11/1972
9/15/1992
12/9/1980
0000-00-00
2000-00-00
1988-00-00
0000-00
2000-10-10
6/25/1976
6/6/1987
8/24/1987
0000-00-00
2000-00-00
```

How can I get year in seperate column in dataframe pandas ?

Comment: Do you want a separate column for each different date format?

Comment: From what I can see from your example, you can use regex to extract the year as they all have 4 digits. Let me  know if you need the code.

Comment: Ya, I can try it

Comment: Thanks everyone,  @princelySid it worked

Answer (score 1):

First convert the column into same format then extract the year from it.

```
import datetime as dt

df['date'] = df.date.apply(
lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')[0])

df['year']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m/%d/%Y').dt.year
```

Comment: The data is more than 20,00,000 records so can't convert into the same format manually.

Comment: I have given the code above to change it in same format.

Comment: 000-00-00 can't be converted, ValueError: year is out of range

Comment: what is your requirement? It should return 0000 or NaT?

Comment: `re.search("(\d{4})",date_entry)`  should extract the year i think

Answer (score 1):

Following approach help in solving the issue:

```
df['year'] = df.date.str.extract(r'([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])', expand=True)
```